# CSS3 succeed and fail in the same page

Tags: css, css3pie

I cannot figure out, in a single page, why [CSS3PIE](http://www.css3pie.com) works on the outside page shadow but not work on the shadow of the photos in IE8. Everything work fine in other browsers.

I am using `#page` for the outside page div and 
`#facilities_maintable tr>td.column2 img` for the photos in the page content.

```
#page 
{
    position:relative; 
    width: 1024px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top:0px;
    background-image: url('../../content/img/bg4.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color: #efebe0;

    -webkit-box-shadow: #222 0px 0px 8px;
    -moz-box-shadow: #222 0px 0px 8px;
    box-shadow: #222 0px 0px 8px;

    behavior: url('../../Content/PIE.htc');
}

#facilities_maintable tr>td.column2 img
{
    margin:5px 15px 5px 15px; 
    border:1px solid #666;
    -webkit-box-shadow: #777 3px 3px 5px;
    -moz-box-shadow: #777 3px 3px 5px;
    box-shadow: #777 3px 3px 5px;
    behavior: url('../../Content/PIE.htc');
}
```

Comment: Try reducing your selectors. Do you need all this `#facilities_maintable tr>td.column2 img` --> `.column2 img`

Answer (score 3):

just set `td {border-collapse: separate;}`
i know, looks strange, but works

Answer (score 0):

Safari to version 5.1, Chrome to version 10.0 and iOS support a property-webkit-box-shadow.

Firefox to version 4.0 supports property-moz-box-shadow.

Internet Explorer up to version 9.0 does not support the property box-shadow.But you can use non-standard property of the filter:

```
filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.dropshadow (offX = 5, offY = 5, color = # 000000);
```